# Android edit another user's SharedPreferences

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, android-notifications, android-package-managers

I am trying to make a group system in my app.

Whenever a user is added to a group by its admin, it should appear that joined group into user's menu.

Should I use push notifications or is there another way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

If you want all users know immediately about adding a new user to a group the best way is as you propose, with push notifications. If you do not need to know this information immediately you can make a request to a server when the application is open and know if there are new users.

Comment: But if he has the application openned in the app list, will this second option work?

Comment: Another possibility is to make a service (program that runs on background even if the app is closed) that makes requests to the server every x seconds/minutes to know if there are new users.